# Limit my app usage to increase the download greed among users?

Tags: user-behavior

Not limiting the whole app as such but the most important feature.

For example if I have 3 options x,y and z and Z being the most important, I could limit it's usage ? Like limiting option z to 1 time a day ? or 6 times a week?

Will this make user little greedy about the app? Or is it a bad idea as my users may spend less time on the app?

Need to be careful about this.

Something like:
[image]

**Update:**

Basically the queries are related to Astrology and the response is given for the same.So is it OK to limit user for such queries ?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question here - if the feature is much sought after then limiting it *could* increase a drive to use it whenever it next becomes available (the Two Dots games uses this: "Lives regenerate every 20 minutes") but could also potentially lead to frustration and users abandoning the app altogether. Context is everything here.

Comment: Will the counter refill?

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho yeah the counter needs to be re-filled

Comment: Adults don't tolerate frustration very well, especially when there's no payoff that's important to them.  So if your application is for use by adults, avoid frustrating them.

Comment: How do they get around the restriction? I've made an assumption below it's going to relate to cost, but could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Although what you're doing isn't exactly **[gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)**, you may find the techniques helpful.

Often a time- and effort-based token economy is used along with a token exchange system to convert digital assets into currency. The objective is to encourage addictive behaviors in users. It would be helpful to understand some basic behavioral science concepts, such as [intermittent reinforcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement#Intermittent_reinforcement_schedules) and [extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_(psychology)). Contrary to statements in the comments, you *do* want to induce some "frustration", but it has to be done in a controlled manner. Casinos are expert at this.

I have no idea what you mean by "make user little greedy about the app". However, your astrology program is analogous to a slot machine, the simplest game. The reward is the prediction, which may be good or bad. Whether this is enough to keep users coming back for more is up for debate, but there is a cohort of people who enjoy reading daily astrology columns.

Comment: I wouldn't call what he is suggesting gamification as he's trying to increase revenue through restriction, not arbitrary rewards for participation.

Comment: But you'd agree, money isn't the simple answer? Nike's app for example, there's no cost to the app, but gamification plays a large part.

Comment: Semantics don't really bother me, more concerned with labelling an issue and constraining our response, you're right - the OP could add more information as to how this is perceived to work.

Comment: @DarrylGodden On further thought, it isn't exactly gamification, but I think the techniques are applicable. Have edited answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

It's ideal if you have the resources to test it with a limited number of users before applying it to all of them. That's how Spotify used to roll out new features - they would define a geo-sector which can see the updated version and then they record the metrics of this feature usage and retention changes. Then they decide about rolling back or adopting this feature to the whole audience.

I would support this idea. The idea of astrology is to give some food for thoughts and as with every food - it's better to be limited so the value of every piece is higher. The question about frequency is harder - you may need to rely on some research.

You may also need to have a valid reason for limiting the attempts (which can increase the perceived value as well) - most of our reactions are connected with what do we feel about it. No one is angry that iPhones are expensive - there is a good reason for this.

There are some extra opportunities in limiting - you may grant some extra attempts for some random astro events which may increase the feeling of unpredictable miracles around.

Overall - astrology gives a sense of belonging to life itself. The act of asking has its own value and inflicts inner changes in a user. You may have very interesting interviews to uncover this.